# Do we need to transcode mp4 or mp3 to HLS format for streaming video/ audio on mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, video, ffmpeg

We are developing a mobile app which play music and video .

The music (.mp3) and video(.mp4)  is about 5 - 20 MB . I knew we must to transcode from .mp4 to HLS format ( .m3u8) for streaming.  And I still consider about transcode audio file to HLS format whether or not ?

I have two question.

1. Do we need transcode video (.mp4) to HLS format if the files are about 5- 20 MB.
2. Do we need transcode mp3 file to HLS format if the files are about 5 - 10 MB ?

Answer (score 2):

> Do we need transcode video (.mp4) to HLS format if the files are about 5- 20 MB.

No.  These are very small.  No need to bother with segments, as they won't be a whole lot smaller than the original file anyway.  You will have better compatibility with MP4 as-is.  Just make sure you use `faststart` when encoding your MP4 files.

> Do we need transcode mp3 file to HLS format if the files are about 5 - 10 MB ?

No.  Again, these are small and you have better compatibility for just streaming them as-is.

Comment: Thanks for more detail. However, if we don't need to transcode to HLS format. How about the bandwidth of system ? Can the system serve a lot of requests at the same time. Because the system need to keep connection open until the mobile app finish to download media file ?

Comment: Yes. In fact, there is less load and overhead by doing this directly than if you were to make a ton of requests via HLS. Lots of simultaneous connections is no problem for modern web servers like Nginx and others.